# Grep directory name

Tags: apache, looking-for-a-script, linux, apache-log-files

Need a script to grep within a directory for folders named by emails (so looking for the @) to then search the apache logs to see if the email address grep'ed has accessed the website today.

Then after this I need to look at the user-agents detail to see what browser they are using

Comment: Apache logs don't tell you someone's email address, unless you're managing to somehow get it into the URL. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @paulmorriss I have folders which are named by email address - these are shown in apache so need to grep these from apache logs to show what email address are being used - hopefully know what browser type as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in `ls emaildir/*@*`
do
grep $i logfile | grep '\['`date +%d/%b/%Y` | awk -F\" '{print $6}' 
done
```

Where emaildir is the directory of files containing email addresses and logfile is the apache logfile.

What it's doing is this:

- getting each file in the email directory with an @ in the filename
- searching the log file for lines containing that filename
- then searching those lines for today's date in the format used by logfiles
- then splitting the line at quote marks and printing the sixth part, which is the browser string

Comment: if I need to only extract lines with today's date [10/Jun/2011:16:34:56 +0100] whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I've updated the answer to add an extra step searching for that date.

Comment: thank for updating - I've had a thought over the weekend as I need to only search the script for todays date so I possibly could use the linux date format to get this in (date +"[%d/%b/&Y") but not sure how to get it in

Comment: thank you for updating - I've had a thought over the weekend as I need to only search the script for todays date so I possibly could use the linux date format to get this in (date +"[%d/%b/&Y") but not sure how to get it in

Comment: I've updated with a date command to get that.